# Django @login_required decorator does not redirect to specific page

Tags: django, login-required

I'm trying to make a limited user edit page if the login is not executed.

After logging in, the edit page opens with any user_id in the url.

Although edit page should be open only with user_id already logged in user.

For example, I logged in with user_id=7, so only one next url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/7/edit) have to have access to edit page.

And this edit page is available by any next urls also (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user//edit)

Are there any errors or mistakes in my code?

I already have cleared cache in Opera and Chrome, but issue still exist.

Django ver. 1.11.9.

LOGIN_URL is not defined in settings.py

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', user_login, name='user-login',),
    url(r'^(?P<user_id>\d+)/edit$', user_edit, name='user-edit',),
]
```

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
    login_form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            print("next is {}".format(request.GET.get('next')))
            return redirect(user_edit, user.id)
        else:
            return redirect(user_login)

    return render(request, 'user_login.html', {'form': login_form})


@login_required(login_url='/user/login/')
def user_edit(request, user_id):
    print(request, request.user)
    print("next is {}".format(request.GET.get('next')))
    return render(request, 'user_edit.html', {'userid': user_id, 'user': request.user})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `login_required` decorator only checks that the user is logged in. If you want to check that the logged-in user has access to an object, then you need to do that in the view. For example:

```
from django.http import Http404

@login_required(login_url='/user/login/')
def user_edit(request, user_id):
    print(request, request.user)
    if request.user.id != user_id:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'user_edit.html', {'userid': user_id, 'user': request.user})
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion
but i need to redirect any not logged in user

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `login_required` decorator redirects any user that is not logged in.